# How do I specify s and w for a morlet wavelet in scipy.signal.cwt?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to tune the s and w parameter in the `scipy.signal.cwt` wavelet transform

```
fs=2048
w = 6
f = 1
s = w*fs / (2*f*np.pi)
widths = np.arange(1, 100)
cwtmatr = signal.cwt(np.random.rand(10000), signal.morlet, widths, w=w, s=s)
```

but I have an issue saying

```
TypeError: morlet() got multiple values for argument 'w'
```

Although w can be tuned as it is a kwargs in the morlet prototype :

```
scipy.signal.morlet(M, w=5.0, s=1.0, complete=True)
```

How can I set s and w when I call the `scipy.signal.cwt` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[scipy.signal.morlet](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.morlet.html) is incompatible with [scipy.signal.cwt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.cwt.html), as stated  in a "Note" at the bottom of the documentation page and in the "See Also" box of [scipy.signal.morlet2](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.morlet2.html). Therefore, you should use `morlet2` - the following example is included in the documentation:

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t, dt = np.linspace(0, 1, 200, retstep=True)
fs = 1/dt
w = 6.
sig = np.cos(2*np.pi*(50 + 10*t)*t) + np.sin(40*np.pi*t)
freq = np.linspace(1, fs/2, 100)
widths = w*fs / (2*freq*np.pi)
cwtm = signal.cwt(sig, signal.morlet2, widths, w=w)
plt.pcolormesh(t, freq, np.abs(cwtm), cmap='viridis', shading='gouraud')
plt.show()
```

which produces

[image]

You can directly provide Omega0 in the call to `cwt` through the keyword `w`. For the width parameter of the wavelet `s`, it is already included in the `widths` argument of `cwt`: `cwt` will loop over each value in widths and provide it to `morlet2`. You can readily see this in the [source code of cwt](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/signal/wavelets.py#L389-L481).

Comment: I don't understand how I can set the scales according to particular frequencies. does `s=widths` here? so I can use `widths = w*fs / (2*f*np.pi)`

Comment: Each value, `width`, in `widths` will be automatically given as an `s` to `morlet2` when you call `cwt` in a similar way as illustrated by the Scipy example. Additionally, the first argument given to `morlet2`, `N`, is computed according to `N = np.min([10 * width, len(data)])` where `data` is the first argument given to `cwt`. In the example you give in the OP, therefore, `N` will always be `10 * width`.