# How to set scale and parameter w in wavelet transform (scipy)?

Tags: python, numpy, math, wavelet, wavelet-transform

I try do a wavelet transform on a signal.
The signal is recorded with 500 Hz (: 500 datapoints per second). I just want to do a wavelet transform on 0.2 seconds of the signal (-> 100 datapoints).

I am really not sure how to define parameter "w" and also if the y-axis is scaled correctly? I cannot find anything in the documentation of scipy to "w".
My code and output looks as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

t, dt = np.linspace(0, 0.2, 100, retstep=True)
fs = 1/dt
w = 6.

sig = sig[0:100] # 0.2 seconds of the signal

freq = np.linspace(1, fs/2, 100)
widths = w*fs / (2*freq*np.pi)
cwtm = signal.cwt(sig, signal.morlet2, widths, w=w)
plt.pcolormesh(t, freq, np.abs(cwtm), cmap='jet', shading='gouraud')

plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Scale")

plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Bonus question: How would you interprete the output in two sentences?

Comment: Could you please include the relevant `import` lines?

Comment: Ok I have included them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67997557/how-do-i-specify-s-and-w-for-a-morlet-wavelet-in-scipy-signal-cwt might help - it mentions the `w`